# use of hyphens in table not working

Tags: mysql

I had a table name called `emp-reg` in mysql.When I gave desc `emp-reg` it showed me an error.

Where as when I changed the table name `RENAME TABLE  emp-reg TO  emp` and then gave `desc emp` it worked perfectly.Why is desc not working for`-`

what will happen if we perform insert operation in table such as`emp-reg`?

Comment: Do not use hyphens in table/column names. use hyphens for minus, and leave it at that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, you can use `_` under score.
`-` is treated as `minus` sign and hence is rejected.

Or you can use back ticks around the name with `-` in it. Say

```
 `emp-reg`.
```

If you want to rename any of such columns in your table, use `alter table` command with `change` option.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE COLUMN `old-col-name` `new_col_name` int
```

You can use any desired or matching data type for the column with the earlier definition.

Comment: Yes. When have `-`, or any other key/reserved words in entity names, you have to use back ticks surrounding them.

Comment: You should better not use them as part of the entity names.

Comment: ,how about renaming a column like emp-yr to empyr

Comment: Whichever. But follow the rules mentioned in the comments.

Comment: ,so the only way is to delete this column and create another without hyphens ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46955/discussion-between-ravinder-and-codelover)